# how to select distinct value from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to get distinct values from 3 tables.

When I perform this code:

```
select DISTINCT(city) from a,b,c
```

I get an error which says that my column 'city' is ambiguous.

Also I have tried this:

```
select DISTINCT(city) from a NATURAL JOIN b NATURAL JOIN c
```

With this code I receive nothing from my tables.

Let me show you on the example of what I am trying to do:

```
TABLE A               TABLE B                TABLE C
id  |  city           id  |  city            id  | city
1   |  Krakow         1   |  Paris           1   | Paris
2   |  Paris          2   |  London          2   | Krakow
3   |  Paris          3   |  Oslo
4   |  Rome
```

And I need to get result like this

```
RESULTS
 city
 ----
 Krakow
 Paris
 Rome
 London
 Oslo
```

Order of the cities is not important to me I just need to have them all, and there should be only one representation of each city.

Any idea? I was thinking to use `id's` in the `JOIN` but there are not connected so I can't use that.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The [`UNION`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) keyword will return `unique` records on the result list. When specifying `ALL` ([*UNION ALL*](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)) will keep duplicates on the result set, which the OP don't want.

```
SELECT city FROM tableA
UNION
SELECT city FROM tableB
UNION
SELECT city FROM tableC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/442ef/1)

RESULT

```
╔════════╗
║  CITY  ║
╠════════╣
║ Krakow ║
║ Paris  ║
║ Rome   ║
║ London ║
║ Oslo   ║
╚════════╝
```

Comment: Exactly what I need. This UNION is like DISTINCT? can you explain it a bit?

Comment: I don't know why this answer has been downvoted. hehe As far as I know, I understood the question. `:)` Let's hear from the downvoter's point of view.

Comment: @user123_456 see my updated answer. also demo here [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/442ef/8)

Comment: okay I have only one question if you don't mind. If I have a additional column in each of the tables  for example `spa_column` where do I need to put where clause so it affects on all tables.

Comment: wrap the whole query in a subquery,  [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/442ef/10)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25881/discussion-between-user123-456-and-jw)

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT city FROM A
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT city FROM B
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT city FROM C
```

Comment: this also produce correct answer but why do you need to add `DISTINCT` keyword with `UNION` will always return unique records unless `ALL` is specified? [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/442ef/7)

Comment: You're quite right. "UNION" defaults to "UNION DISTINCT" (rather than "UNION ALL")